# Programming in NetBeans at school and home with different Java JDK versions

Tags: java, netbeans, versions

So basically, at school our machines have an older version of the Java JDK installed, and I want to work on a netbeans project on home.  I have it set up through the github and wanted to know if switching between JDK versions will mess up my project at all, if the older version will allow me to even open the newer version. And, if I can't, was curious on how to open a project in an older version of the JDK.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just simply need to not use language features introduced after the version your school uses. Netbeans will give you hints if you attempt to use something when the version doesn't support it however (e.g. Diamond operators in 6, or using Lambdas when not using Java 8). So overall I would say you shouldn't be running into any issues, you can even make netbeans recognize the sources as an older version of Java by right clicking your project, and going to:

> Properties > Sources > Source/Binary > 1.6 (Or whatever version you need)